# font face working in screen media but not in print media

Tags: css, printing, screen

i used code below outside my print and screen media code works on screen media but not in print media

```
<style type="text/css">


@font-face {
    font-family: dinregular;
    src: url('/images/templateImages/template9/din-regular-italic.ttf')


</style>
```

what could be the possible causes due to which my font face not working when i download my template as pdf, it is working when i see my template on browser

any help appreciated

Answer (score 1):

I've tested in Firefox and chrome, font-face does not work in @media print, it is ignored by browsers.

Comment: then what is alternate,so that we can use fonts in print media

Comment: I have no idea. Having tested base64 and other font formats, but failed again. W3 says that: "In cases where user agents have limited platform resources or implement the ability to disable downloadable font resources, @font-face rules must simply be ignored;", maybe this is the case :(

Answer (score 0):

.ttf will not work everywhere. You will need to include the font in multiple formats to make sure it works everywhere. Font Squirrel has a nice tool that will let you upload a font file, convert it to the needed formats and give you the css to include.

http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator

That will make your font work in every browser and hopefully also your pdf file. If that does not work you might have to embed the font by converting the font to base64.

Comment: what type of fonts are supported in print media